# run Yii Interactive Tool with xampp on windows

Tags: yii, xa

I want to config yii on windows, but i can not run Yii Interactive Tool. all documents i read is for Linux that have below syntax:

%YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell

but i am using xampp on windows, how can i do this?

Comment: You can still use yiic with XAMPP, that's what I do.  What error are you getting that's stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to do with the tool? If it's code generation use the web-based [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) instead.